# Why does Tor Browser Bundle 3.5 not save preferences?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I was wondering if others are having the issue I am having and if any one knows a solution. The problem is I recently updated to Tor 3.5 and modified some settings in about:config and via Options but when I restart Tor with the prefs.js having been modified I get an error stating that Tor Browser Bundle has stopped working with an option to check online for a solution or close the program. I have to delete prefs.js, thus losing my setting, in order for it to start again. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. If anyone has any idea about this and how to correct it please let me know.

Comment: This might be expected behaviour; playing with Firefox settings may make you easier to fingerprint.

Comment: I guess prefs are stored across sessions, or at least this is the case with the Linux 3.5 version. @user796, could you try to see if it crashes for any pref change or there is a specific pref that causes trouble? (e.g. toggle top-most (accessibility...) setting in about:config and see if still crashes or not...)

Answer (score 2):

Well I think I figured it out. It wasn't the about:config settings. And all of the setting changes in 'options' were fine too except for one which was causing the problem. I had checked the box to 'use hardware acceleration when available' and that was causing the problem. I have that box checked in my regular Firefox 26 build without issue so must be an issue with the Tor browser bundle and not the hardware acceleration on my computer.